# Emacs --no-window-system menu

Tags: emacs

I've noticed that once

```
$ emacs -nw
```

is called, the usual *emacs* menu appears on the upper part of the terminal.

**QUESTION**

How does one use that menu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emacs gives a handy intro which mentions this, if you start it without loading a file.  If you always give a filename on the command-line, you won't see it.  Here's how to use it:

> Activate menubar   F10  or  ESC `or   M-`

Comment: Thank you! it worked with the F10 key. However, the system also understand this as a mouse Right-click. :-P I guess is an Ubuntu issue.